# Como combinar el historico de GIT de una migracion SVN erronea

Tags: git, svn

Tengo un repositorio GIT migrado desde SVN. 
Debido a que se copió una carpeta en el SVN el historico no se ha migrado correctamente. Lo intento explicar gráficamente:

```
SVN :  r1    \ --> carpeta raiz --> Projecto1 \ fichero1
                                                fichero2 
  . 
  .  pasa el tiempo... y no vuelve
  .
  . 
SVN :  r1000 \ --> carpeta raiz
               --> Proyecto1 \ fichero1
                               fichero2
                    ^
                    |
                    ------> Despues de un tiempo, esta carpeta se migra a GIT
```

Debido al cambio, la historia completa no se ha migrado a GIT (solo aparece desde r1000 hasta HEAD) 
Ahora queremos añadir este historico perdido dentro del repositorio GIT migrado, (desde r1000 a r1 ), pero este repositorio ya está en uso y la intención es que el historico apareza despues :

```
GIT_ACTUAL --> A (1.2018) - B (2.2018) - C (3.2018) - D (HEAD)
VIEJOS_LOGS --> E (1.2016) ... F (1.2017)
```

La idea es que se quede algo como esto :

```
WORKING --> E ... F --> A - B - C
```

Los ficheros son los mismos y estaría bien mantener la historia, las pruebas que he hecho no he conseguido mezclarlo correctamente. ¿alguna sugerencia?

#### UPDATE: Más detalles

Migré los repositorios haciendo:

```
URL=http://server.name/project1
git svn clone --authors-file=authors.txt $URL -r1000:HEAD first-migration
```

Tiempo después hice:

```
URL=http://server.name/common/
git svn clone --authors-file=authors.txt $URL -r1:1000 second_migration
cd second_migration
git filter-branch
```

Ahora tenemos dos repositorios, first-migration que está en uso y se usa para el desarrollo actual y second_migration, que contiene las revisiones antiguas (de 1-1000)
Lo que he conseguido hasta ahora :

```
mkdir migration
cd migration
git init
git remote add newest ssh://gitserver:first-migration
git remote add older  ssh://gitserver:second-migration
git remote update 
git checkout newest/master -b new.master
git checkout 1abc2def3   -b new.firstcommit 
git checkout older/master -b old.master
git rebase --preserve-merges --root --committer-date-is-author-date new.master
git checkout new.master -b master
git remote add fullhistory ssh://gitserver:final.git
git push fullhistory --all
```

En este caso new.firstcommit es el primer commit que se hizo durante la primera migración.
Despues de estas operaciones la historia está disponible pero aparece "desconectada". 
[image: Historias desconectadas]

Mi pregunta es sobre todo como integrar la historia antigua de la mejor manera. (no hay problema en crear un repositorio nuevo)

Comment: fijate si el ejemplo de http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/rebase_without_tears.html cuando hace `git rebase --onto master --root   other-branch` sirve de pista, hay una variante extendida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de [alo-malbarez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/81450/alo-malbarez) he podido conseguir lo que buscaba.
El proceso se concluye haciendo lo siguiente:

```
git checkout old.master
git cherry-pick new.firstcommit
# No creo que sea necesario hacer esto, pero prefiero dejar constancia  
git commit --allow-empty -m "Mixing histories"
git rebase -s recursive -Xtheirs --onto old.master new.firstcommit new.master
git push --all --tags
```

Finalmente parece que ya consigo mezclar historias correctamente.